# How to retrieve the week value from the django model to view and pass it to the dictionary?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I just want to retrieve the week value from the model to view and pass it to the dictionary. What am I doing wrong?

**Model**

```
import datetime
from datetime import date
from django.db import models


class WeekNumber(models.Model):
    """Week number"""
    objects = models.Manager()

    @staticmethod
    def number_of_week():
        week = date.today().strftime("%U")
        return week
```

**View**

```
from django.views import View
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import WeekNumber


class WeekNumbers(View):
    model = WeekNumber
    template_name = 'week_number'

    def get(self, request):
        week = WeekNumber.objects.get()
        context = {'week': week}
        return render(request, 'week_number.html', context)
```

**Template**

```
<tr>
  <td>Week {{ week }}</td>
</tr>
```

and I have in browser:

`Week WeekNumber object (1)`

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What output did you expect? Although it's a little hard to understand why you would define a model with *no fields* and only a staticmethod. If you wanted the output of the staticmethod, you would need to actually call it. But again, doing this makes no sense.

Comment: Thank you for asking. About the output: I wanted to display the number of the current week (for example, today it is 47). I created such a model, because I do not yet understand why models are needed at all. Now I understand that there is no need to create a model for data that does not need to be stored in a database.

Comment: In fact you can do this directly in the template, with `{% now "W" %}`, see the [template tags docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#now).

Comment: Thank you again, it is precisely what do I want to learn. Please design your comment as an answer so that I can mark the task as solved.